# Actions Menu Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there any way to remove 'Chart' from Actions Menu in an Interactive Grid?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I posted a short answer that should have honestly probably been a comment with a link to https://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2017/01/24/how-to-hack-apex-interactive-grid-part-2/

Then I had some time and decided to try to actually execute this and got to a solution thanks to https://community.oracle.com/thread/4324589 where they also further reference https://community.oracle.com/thread/4319050

So you know where to go for more information on this topic.

As for your solution:

Go into the Attributes of the IG, Find Javascript Initialization Code under Advanced.
Then paste the following code:

```
function(config) {

    var toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar();
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    toolbarData.toolbarRemove( "chart-view" );  
    return config;

}
```

Hope this works for you, it worked for me.

EDIT:

In response to you asking how to find the name to remove.

Well thats not exactly simple. See if perhaps its mentioned in one of the posts. Otherwise you will have to search through the js file.

How I went about it is that once on the page, I opened up the console and ran `$.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar();`
, opened up the returned array, and jumped to the definition of ToolbarRemove. This opened up InteractiveGrid.min.js so I could search there. Then I Ctrl + F there to find "chart".

What you could also do so you arent just searching blindly until you find it is that these labels need to be referenced for translation. So if you go to
http://translate-apex.com
And you find what the label is called, you can just search for that.
For the chart you could go to the translations and find the Chart item which is APEX.IG.CHART. Then in the js you find APEX.IG.CHART which only occurs once, instead of the 10 times "chart" occurs.

EDIT 2:

You asked about the Flashback dialog.

```
function(config) {

    var toolbarData = $.apex.interactiveGrid.copyDefaultToolbar();
    config.toolbarData = toolbarData;
    toolbarData.toolbarRemove( "show-flashback-dialog" );  
    return config;

}
```

This works for me

Comment: If I want to remove any thing else, how to find the name of the field that is mentioned in brackets?

Comment: How to hide a sub-menu item? I am trying to hide 'Flashback' from the Data submenu. I can hide all other sub menu items by using actions.hide("show-aggregate-dialog");, etc., however when I try to hide flashback using actions.hide("show-flashback-dialog");, nothing happens. Can you help me in this as well?

Comment: @AbhinavDhiman check the second edit. What you tried should work, but tried it myself and it indeed doesent, weird. But this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Check the attributes of the interactive grid and turn off the "Define chart view"

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr71j.png)

Comment: This removes the entire actions menu

Comment: Nope .. I tried it myself .. it only removes the chart icon .. if it is removing all actions menu then you must have pressed different sliders before pressing this one

Comment: Yes, I apologise. You are indeed correct. I had changed a different setting also.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using Oracle APEX 5.1, which doesn't have this feature.