# Oracel Apex Customize your Action Menu

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have an interactive Apex report and want to customize the actions which the user can use.
e.g. i want to remove the "Data"-Option in the menu you can see on the Picture.

I already tried to find an Option in Apex, but i didn't found it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iruNR.png

Comment: Others have pointed out solutions using the options in APEX. But some things are harder to remove than that so I went back and found my answer to a similar question. Maybe this will help you out:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62301165/actions-menu-interactive-grid/62302352#62302352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apex 5.1, you need to go to App Builder --> Interactive Report element ( not the report itself but the object interactive report associated to it )

[image]

Then , you must disable the child elements the DATA OPTION

[image]

Once is done, then you will see that the data option is no longer in the menu

**Update**

To access the component view of any apex application

Enter the Workspace --> Application Builder --> Select your application and press double click --> Then you are in your application, you only need to select the page that contains the interactive report you want to modify.

Once you are in the Page designer, you will see two main sections ( Layout and Component View ). There are more, but these are the main ones. You need to switch to the component view.

There is no way to deactivate the Component view in the Page Designer. If you don't have access to the Page Designer is probably because you don't have a developer user. In Apex, besides the administrators, there are two type of users: Developers and End Users. Developers have access to the Page Designer, End Users don't.

[image]

Comment: @Lukas_Multi, if the answer solves your problem, please accept it.

Comment: Where do you find the option which you can see on the first Screenshot? 
I can't find it.

Comment: the first picture is the COMPONENT VIEW  in Apex Application Builder

Comment: After the last update i can't find the COMPONENT VIEW any more. Is there a Setting to activate it?

Comment: do you have access to the app builder ? I will update the answer to show you in pictures where to find it

Comment: Before i updated it was shown in the Page Editor. I used it already. Since the update to `Application Express 20.1.0.00.13` i cant find it any more.

Comment: Read my update. The operative for this is the same in apex 5 than in Apex 19c. I have no Apex 20, so I don't know if that has changed, but I doubt it.

Comment: This is how it looks to me.
[link](https://imgur.com/99Hsvl0)

Comment: by default, 20c has disabled that part. There is an icon of tools in your menu. Please, check this youtube video , is quite easy to enable it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-yPSJGY-_Y

Comment: The youtube video shows a tutorial of Project Professional. Maybe you send me the wrong link.

Edit: found it by my self. The Link is [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYbE0Hf9lbo)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 5.x any more and can't remember which options it has, but - in 18.x, you'd navigate to interactive report's **attributes**. In there, under "Actions Menu", there's an option to enable (or disable) various menu items. See if something like that exists in your version.